# Override standard New button in Lightning Experience

Tags: visualforce, lightning, lightning-experience

Currently the only way to override a standard New button on any object is via a Visualforce page, in both LEX and Classic.

In LEX the standard behaviour when one click on a New button is to open up a modal window with form to enter the values of the new record's fields.

When I override the New button with a visualforce page, when in LEX clicking on the New button simply opens the visuaforce page, no modal window.

Does this mean that to replicate the LEX when overriding the New button we need to provide the modal functionality ourselves ?

Thanks,
Fernando

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless your Visualforce is creating a [modal](http://www.salesforcegeneral.com/salesforce-modal-dialog-box/) window, your "New" page will not display as an extra layer above the app. You could consider looking into [modal components](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/modals/) and create your own "New" form.

If you are unfamiliar with the LEX rollout I would strongly suggest you take some time to complete the Develop for [Lightning Experience](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trails/lex_dev) Trailhead. This will take you from understanding what is LEX up to the LEX Design System.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @TSmith. You answered my questions because you are saying that the visualforce needs to crate and open the modal window, which is fair enough. I would have thought that the Salesforce would automatically open the visualforce within a modal when overriding standard functionality to enforce the user expirience, but it seems is up to te visualforce to open the modal.